# Monetdbe Python UDF

Tags: monetdb

Given that `monetdbe` is a Python package, I'm optimistic that Python user-defined-functions are possible, but I haven't been able to find an example. I've tried this:

```
drop function every_other_letter;

create function every_other_letter(s string)
returns string
language python {
     letters = "".join(s[::2])
     return letters
};

select every_other_letter('foobarbaz');
```

I get this error:

```
ParseException:SQLparser:42000!Internal error while compiling statement: TypeException:user.p2_1[4]:'pyapi3.eval' library error in: Embedded Python 3 has not been enabled. Start server with --set embedded_py=3
```

Is there any way to set these flags in the embedded version?

Comment: Can you share your reasons for wanting to use Python in monetdb in Python?

Comment: @ArisKoning, sure. I have a UI that sends some queries to an embedded Monet instance. A user can't run arbitrary Python scripts, but I thought making a UDF would be ok. I'm mostly working with datascientists, so they would easily understand a Python example.

Comment: Ah, interesting use case. I see why LANGUAGE PYTHON becomes appealing then. You might consider adding a feature request for this on MonetDBe-Python's github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LANGUAGE PYTHON` UDF's are a nice development feature in MonetDB's server installation but this feature requires an additional Python module to be loaded. And there is currently no way to configure `monetdbe` to load the required python module.

However assuming you have performance requirement for some production setting that are not met with the out-of-the-box SQL toolset in monetdbe, it makes more sense to implement a custom UDF extension written in C/C++. In regular MonetDB's server installation, the database server `mserver5` can load an arbitrary extension module using the `--loadmodule=<module>` command option.  But there is no equivalent `monetdbe_option` as of yet.

You might consider adding a feature request for this on monetdbe-python's github repository.

However there seems to exist a functioning undocumented workaround for adding UDF extensions to `monetdbe`. During its initialization, `monetdbe` attempts to load a set of hard coded modules. One of those is a module named `"udf"`. You can create your own implementation of this module and load it into `monetdbe`.

Creating a native UDF extension is outside of the scope of this question and answer but there exist a nice up-to-date tutorial for writing UDF extensions for MonetDB [here](https://www.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB-extend/). Following the steps described in that tutorial, you end up with a SQL function `revstr` which has a user defined native implementation. The following Python script demonstrate its use:

```
from monetdbe import connect

with connect(autocommit=True) as con:
    cur = cur.execute("select revstr('abcde')")
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print(result)
```

Make sure that the library containing your UDF extension is in the search path of the dynamic linker:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path to directory containing lib_udf> python test.py
```

Comment: Thanks! My C/C++ skills are pretty weak at the moment, so I will try some of the other languages first, but good to know that there is a workaround if I really need it. Or maybe there is some way to write these things in Python and have a program translate it to C that can be imported so as to work with the tutorial.